# Regex works in VS Code search/replace but not in sed script

Tags: bash, sed

I realize this question has been asked 100 times on Stack Overflow already. Despite reading the many questions and answers I am still stuck.

Start: `https://website.com/page.html?q=term,tag-one,tag-two,tag-three,15`

Goal: `https://website.com/page.html,tag-one,tag-two,tag-three,15`

*Edit: `term` represents any string, including something like search%20term*

This works successfully in VS Code search/replace:

Search: `\?.*?,`

Replace: `,`

However when used in a Bash script, this: `sed -E 's|\?.*?,|,|'`

Results in this: `https://website.com/page.html,15`

While surprisingly to me, this works: `sed -E 's|#.*?,|,|'`

My thinking was that:

- `s` means substitute
- escaping `\?` tells the command to find literal question marks
- `.*?,` tells the command  to grab any character until the first comma it comes to
- `g` is not needed in the command
- `-E` allows sed to recognize more Regexes than -e

This is my basic lay-person understanding and probably erroneous.

Is anyone able to educate me on what is going on? Thank you if so.

Comment: My thinking was that `s`=substitute; escaping `\?` tells it to find literal question marks; `.*?,` tells it to grab any character until the first comma it comes to. However ChrisBrownie55 is telling me below that sed doesn't respect a non-greedy match. I didn't put `g` in the command because I didn't think I needed it. I added `-E` because as I understand it allows sed to recognize more Regexes than `-e`. This is my basic lay-person understanding and probably erroneous.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I appreciate your time to educate me on posting more effective questions so I get better answers.

Comment: Brilliant! Now people wanting to answer your question knows where you're at. So, what goes awry? The next step is to present the _input_ you _do_ get and the output your `regex` produces - and the output you expect. If you take it piece by piece

Comment: Regarding your title question, "_Regex works in VS Code search/replace but not in sed script_", I should say, don't expect them to.work in the same way. `regex`engines work in _very_ different mysterious ways.

Comment: See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Match any character that is not a `,` (comma)

The issue you're encountering seems to occur because the wildcard `*` matches any character and will subsequently match all of the `,` (commas) until there's only one left (which is matched by the `,` in your regex).

I believe this is due to the `sed` command not respecting the `.*?` non-greedy match that VSCode appears to be respecting. To get around that, we can use a negated character class `[^,]` (the `^` caret tells it to match anything but the `,`).

```sh
sed -E 's|\?[^,]*,|,|'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are true:

- `s` means substitute
- escaping `\?` tells the command to find literal question marks
- `.*?,` tells the command  to grab any character until the first comma it comes to, **but not greedy** unlike `.*`
- `g` is not needed in the command
- `-E` allows sed to recognize more Regexes than -e, ***extented regex***

Like this:

```
sed -E 's|\?[^,]+,|,|'
```

- `[^,]` means *all but not `,`* and `+` means *at least one occurrence*

Or using *intuitive* already workable solution you have done in VS  Code, but now in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's|\?.*?,|,|'
```

**What's happens, it's that the non greedy catch-all regex `.*?` is not recognized by sed. But perl understand it.**

## Output

```
Start: https://website.com/page.html,tag-one,tag-two,tag-three,15
```

Comment: The only _question_ in the question was "_Is anyone able to educate me on what is going on?_"

Comment: Added Perl solution, and I edit the answer now to add explanations

Comment: I'm guessing that more of the same language OP doesn't understand won't help. Why not break your captures down to explain it?

Comment: Added explanations

Comment: Looking at OP:s question, I'm not sure what you just did is _explaining_ anything. OP does not know `regex` enough to just pick it up with what you leave OP with.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer and add explanations. I'm better at shell than explaining in english

Comment: If OP had been present a few minutes back I'd spent my time trying to make the _question_ better instead of pestering you.

Comment: Added some explanations, bold text added to OP good description of the substitution

Comment: Lovely - that's something to build upon! +1 from me.